# Converting PreTeXt to LaTeX

Tags: conversion

Does anyone know how to convert from PreTexT files to straight LaTeX?  I see on the website that it's possible, but I can't find the exact commands.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://mathbook.pugetsound.edu/doc/author-guide/html/quickstart-processing.html) the command:

```
xsltproc /path/to/mathbook/xsl/mathbook-latex.xsl <your-document>.xml
```

should produce the file `article-1.tex` which can be processed with LaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but in case someone else searches and finds it, there is now a much easier way to convert from PreTeXt to LaTeX.  You will need python installed, but then you can install PreTeXt with `pip install pretext`.

Each project needs a project manifest, which you can get with `pretext init`.  You might need to edit the `pretext.ptx` file to point to your source files.

Then to "build" latex you can run `pretext build print-latex`.

This is now included in the [getting started](https://pretextbook.org/doc/guide/html/quickstart-example.html) part of the documentation.

There is also an easy to use extension to VS Code, [PreTeXt-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oscarlevin.pretext-tools), that provides a GUI for this.